# unable to save images more than 19 in cakephp

Tags: image, cakephp

I am new to Cake PHP, when i am trying to add images more than 19, i am able to see 19 images only, rest of the images not getting saved. Can anybody share where will be setting to change limit for number of images to save.

I used file upload in bootstrap.

Thanks,
sck

Comment: what is your code?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

Comment: got 20 images now, how to allow all images to save

Comment: increment size of upload to 1G

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '40M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're limited by the Paginator component, which defaults to max 20 rows per page.

Using CakePHP 4, you could first check for

```php
$this->loadComponent('Paginator');
```

If so, before your controller actions you could set a `$paginate` property:

```php
// Paginate property
public $paginate = [
    'limit' => 100,
];
```

see documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#paginating-multiple-queries

You can also use pagination functionality w/o explicitly loading Paginator component.
Inside a controller action you could just write:

```php
// limits to 20 rows per page (default)   
$this->paginate($this->MyModel);
```

to load max 100 rows you could do:

```php
// increase limit to max 100 rows per page    
$this->paginate($this->MyModel, ['limit' => 100]);
```

see documentation:
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#advanced-usage

Hope this puts you in the right direction.